# swagger-ui 3.0.6 - Add custom authorization header client side (through javascript dropdown onchange event)

Tags: swagger-ui

I'm interested to understand how to auto-add my custom authorization header to all "try it out" requests with swagger-ui 3.0.6.
In my frontend page I have a dropdown that contains multiple *authorization header values*. So, what I did with swagger 2.x it was a javascript function with an onchange event that injected the selected *authorization header* value in the swaggerUI instance.
I cannot reproduce this mechanism with swagger-ui 3.0.6.
Someone could help me?
This question is releated to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42995594/how-to-use-basic-auth-in-swagger-ui-v-3-0/43493272#comment73093040_42995594).
Thanks

Comment: How does your custom `Authorization` header look like?

Comment: X-MyCustomHeader-Name: 'a-value'. With swagger-ui 2.x I do in this way:
`var apiKeyAuth = new SwaggerClient.ApiKeyAuthorization("X-MyCustomHeader-Name", 'a-value', "header");
window.swaggerUi.api.clientAuthorizations.add("api_key", apiKeyAuth);`

Answer (score 0):

> In my frontend page I have a dropdown that contains multiple authorization header values. So, what I did with swagger 2.x it was a javascript function with an onchange event that injected the selected authorization header value in the swaggerUI instance.
>  I cannot reproduce this mechanism with swagger-ui 3.0.6

Adding authorization headers programmatically is not supported yet in Swagger UI 3.0.x. This is being tracked in https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/2793.

Comment: Hi Helen, what you have written is true and works already in my case, so maybe I did not explain my problem well.  In my frontend page I have a dropdown that contains multiple _authorization header values_. So, what I did with swagger 2.x it was a javascript function with an onchange event that injected the selected _authorization header value_ in the swaggerUI instance.<br/>
I cannot reproduce this mechanism with swagger-ui 3.0.6.

Comment: @Luca, you should have added this information to the original question.