# How Can I add basic auth in swagger 3.0 automatically with out the user to type in at authorize button?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-editor, openapi

I am using swagger 3.0 and have multiple endpoints in swagger docs.

I want user not to type in credentials at authorize button every time.

Is there any way I can include authentication in index.html or in my yaml files to automatically authorize the user.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swagger UI 3.13.0+ provides the `preauthorizeBasic` method for this purpose. Assuming your API definition includes a security scheme for Basic auth:

```yaml
swagger: '2.0'
...
securityDefinitions:
  basicAuth:
    type: basic

security:
  - basicAuth: []
```

you can specify the default username and password for Basic auth like so:

```js
// index.html

const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
  url: "https://my.api.com/swagger.yaml",
  ...
  onComplete: function() {
    // "basicAuth" is the key name of the security scheme in securityDefinitions
    ui.preauthorizeBasic("basicAuth", "username", "password");
  }
})
```

Now, if you click the "Authorize" button in Swagger UI, you will see that the username and password are pre-filled.

---

Original answer (for Swagger UI 3.1.6—3.12.1):

You can add the [`requestInterceptor`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/configuration.md#network) to your Swagger UI's *index.html* file in order to add the `Authorization` header automatically to "try it out" requests. `requestInterceptor` is supported in Swagger UI 3.1.6 and later.

```js
// index.html

const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
  url: "http://my.api.com/swagger.yaml",
  ...
  requestInterceptor: (req) => {
    if (! req.loadSpec) {
      // Add the header to "try it out" calls but not spec fetches
      var token = btoa("username" + ":" + "password");
      req.headers.Authorization = "Basic " + token;
    }
    return req;
  }
})
```