# How to send Authorization header with a request in swagger-ui-react?

Tags: reactjs, swagger, swagger-ui

I use swagger-ui-react in my application. But I don't know how to config to add the authorization into api requests.

I had found an answer use in swagger ui from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31057343/adding-basic-authorization-for-swagger-ui):

```
window.swaggerUi = new SwaggerUi({...})
...
swaggerUi.api.clientAuthorizations.add("key", new SwaggerClient.ApiKeyAuthorization("Authorization", "Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=", "header"));
```

But I don't know how to use in swagger-ui-react. Here is my code:

```
import styles from './index.less';

import React from 'react';
// tslint:disable
import SwaggerUI from 'swagger-ui-react';
import 'swagger-ui-react/swagger-ui.css';
// tslint:able

const SwaggerComp = params => {
    const auth = params.authorization;
    return (
        <div className={styles.wrapper}>
         <SwaggerUI
           url="/v2/swagger-file-url"
           withCredentials
         />
       </div>
    )
};

export default SwaggerComp;
```

Comment: Do you mean that the `/v2/swagger-file-url` file requires the `Authorization` header to access it?

Comment: No, the request when I click the swagger ui button 'Try it out'.

I found an answer use in swagger-ui:

```
swaggerUi.api.clientAuthorizations.add("key", new SwaggerClient.ApiKeyAuthorization("Authorization", "Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=", "header"));
```

But I don't know how to use it in swagger-ui-react.

Answer (score 2):

To send the `Authorization` header in "try it out" requests, your API definition file (`/v2/swagger-file-url`) must define the appropriate security for operations. Users will need to click the "Authorize" button to enter the authentication information (such as the username and password for Basic auth) before doing "try it out".

OpenAPI 3.0 example:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.2

components:
  securitySchemes:
    basicAuth:
      type: http
      scheme: basic

security:
  - basicAuth: []
```

OpenAPI 2.0 example:

```yaml
swagger: '2.0'

securityDefinitions:
  basicAuth:
    type: basic

security:
  - basicAuth: []
```

For more information, see:

- [Authentication](http://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/) guide for OpenAPI 3.0
- [Authentication](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/authentication/) guide for OpenAPI 2.0

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I can't change the yaml file so I want other way to set authorization.

Answer (score 0):

In react-swagger-ui, they have a network property called **[requestInterceptor](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/configuration.md)**, in here you can modify the request json before passing it to the api call, so you can add the authorization header in there, and remember to return the modified json in requestInterceptor.

To set up the authentication header in the json, there are a couple ways to do it, I was using sigv4 for authorization header, and I used Amplify Signer to generator all the required header(Authorization, X-Amz-Date..) for me before the api call, this is the link **[here](https://jun711.github.io/aws/how-to-sign-api-gateway-requests-with-signature-version-4-using-aws-amplify/)**.

Comment: I don't know why this answer was voted down, this is the correct answer for anyone  wanting to add their users' accessTokens to requests. Thank you!