# Can I enable the request duration in Swagger UI 2.x with a Docker variable (or in alternative ways)?

Tags: docker, swagger-ui

I know there are different ways to [enable the HTTP request duration in Swagger UI 3.x](https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/usage/configuration/):

> Swagger UI accepts configuration parameters in four locations.
>
> From lowest to highest precedence:
>
> - The `swagger-config.yaml` in the project root directory, if it exists, is baked into the application
> - configuration object passed as an argument to Swagger UI (`SwaggerUI({ ... })`)
> - configuration document fetched from a specified `configUrl`
> - configuration items passed as key/value pairs in the URL query string

For example with a Docker variable:

```
DISPLAY_REQUEST_DURATION="true"
```

I've some API stuck with the older Swagger UI 2.x, though.

- In 2.x, is it possible to enable the duration through the Docker variable?
- If not, what choices do I have to do it *through configuration* (not through software)?

Comment: Just to clarify - by 2.0 and 3.0 do you mean [Swagger UI versions](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/version-detection.md)? Request duration is only available in Swagger UI 3.x, it's not available in UI 2.x.

Comment: Thank you Helen, yes, I meant that. Please turn it into an answer so I can accept it... I suspected it but wanted to be sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Request duration is only available in Swagger UI 3.0.18+, it's not available in v. 2.x

Comment: How painful would it be migrating the UI from 2 to 3, in your opinion?

Comment: If you just host the dist assets without customizations, it should be as simple as replacing the dist assets and updating the `url` in index.html to point to your YAML/JSON file. But in the general case, migration depends on many factors, for example: 1) whether you use UI's dist assets directly or bundled with some library (e.g. Springfox/Swashbuckle); 2) whether you need custom CSS or other look & feel tweaks; 3) whether you need UI localization, support for the old Swagger 1.x Specification, Internet Explorer support - these things are in UI 2.x only. Keep in mind that UI 2.x is EOL.

Comment: Well @Helen, actually is this one: https://github.com/Alfresco/rest-api-explorer/blob/master/src/main/webapp/index.html Apart from the sparse files now reunited in a single CSS and a single JS in v3, I see some jQuery initialization there that I suppose won't be supported anymore in v3, right?

Comment: Yes, jQuery tweaks won't work, the new version uses React. Here're [examples of React-based customizations](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5027#issuecomment-438745785) for the reference. Most configs in `new SwaggerUi(...)` are also supported in v. 3, I think. API definition selector ([this](https://github.com/Alfresco/rest-api-explorer/blob/master/src/main/webapp/index.html#L121)) is now supported using the `urls` config.

Comment: (cont.) Request authentication (`addAuthorization()` in your linked file) is done by adding `securityDefinitions`+`security` to the API definition itself and using the "Authorize" button in Swagger UI. There's also [`preauthorizeBasic`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49637597/113116) to apply auth programmatically.

Comment: Hi Helen, I've finally found the time to migrate it to Swagger UI 3, thank you a lot for your help! It's 99% ready, but there's a small error that I don't know if it's a false positive from Swagger UI 3 or if there's actually something to change in that particular API definition. I'd really appreciate your opinion about it, if you can: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65584131/1654265