# Weird "Could not resolve reference: undefined Not Found" messages in Swagger UI 3

Tags: rest, yaml, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

While migrating Alfresco's [REST API Explorer](https://github.com/Alfresco/rest-api-explorer) from Swagger UI 2 to Swagger UI 3 (3.38.0), a single API definition raised two ***Could not resolve reference: undefined Not Found*** errors at :

```
paths./search.post.parameters.0.schema.properties.pivots.items.properties.pivots.items.$ref
```

and

```
paths./search.post.responses.200.schema.properties.list.properties.context.properties.request.properties.pivots.items.properties.pivots.items.$ref
```

1. All the API definitions were working fine in Swagger UI 2
2. All the API definitions but this work fine in Swagger UI 3
3. The YAML of [this API definition](https://github.com/Alfresco/rest-api-explorer/blob/master/src/main/webapp/definitions/alfresco-search.yaml) seems structurally identical to the YAML of [the other API definitions](https://github.com/Alfresco/rest-api-explorer/tree/master/src/main/webapp/definitions)
4. The Swagger Validator tells me that the YAML is valid:

[image]

I've gone through a lot of different StackOverflow Q&A and GitHub Issues with similar error messages, but they were mostly related to YAML invalid or with unsupported siblings of `$ref`, and it doesn't seem to be the case here.

**Is this a false positive from Swagger UI 3, or is there something wrong with the API definition itself?**

Is there something I can do to avoid getting these messages?

---

In case someone wants an SSCCE:

- download [the branch](https://github.com/Alfresco/rest-api-explorer/tree/feature/ACS-937_migrate-Swagger-UI-to-v3)
- run `mvn jetty:run-war`
- open http://localhost:8085/api-explorer

Then select the `Search API` definition and click on the green row with the `/search` API:

[image]

Comment: The resolver sometimes chokes on deeply nested schemas, long `allOf`+`$ref` chains, and/or circular references. Here are similar issues in Swagger repos: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-js/issues/1570, https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5726, https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5820. Most likely your definition is fine and you're seeing one of those bugs.

Comment: Thank you Helen... That was my feeling, but I wanted some expert opinion about it. If you turn your comment into an answer, I'll accept it and assign the bounty before its expiration.

Comment: By the way, while opening each page the API definition are correctly retrieved with a GET. Only in this page and only after having triggered this error, the GET are two, the usual one ending in 304, and an invalid one ending in 404 (it has `.../definitions/definitions/...` instead of just `.../definitions/...` in the URL). Why is that?

Comment: It's a part / symptom of that resolver bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your API definition is fine. This error is a bug/limitation of Swagger UI's `$ref` resolver - sometimes it fails on long `$ref` + `allOf`/`oneOf`/`anyOf` chains, recursive schemas, circular references, or a combination thereof.

In your example ([alfresco-search.yaml](https://github.com/Alfresco/rest-api-explorer/blob/master/src/main/webapp/definitions/alfresco-search.yaml)), the error is triggered by the recursion in the `RequestPivot` schema:

```yaml
  RequestPivot:
    description: A list of pivots.
    type: object
    properties:
      key:
        description: A key corresponding to a matching field facet label or stats.
        type: string
      pivots:
        type: array
        items:
          $ref: '#/definitions/RequestPivot'
```

Here are related issues in Swagger repos that you can track:
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-js/issues/1570
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5726
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5820

In the meantime, you can hide that red "Errors" block - either by adding a piece of CSS to your `index.html`

```css
.errors-wrapper {
    display: none !important;
}
```

or by using [this plugin](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3366#issuecomment-363258562) to remove the "Errors" block entirely (i.e. not add it to the DOM). The plugin code needs be added before the `SwaggerUIBundle` constructor, and then the plugin name needs to be included in the `plugins` list in the constructor.

```js
// index.html

<script>
window.onload = function() {

  // hide the entire Errors container
  const HideAllErrorsPlugin = () => {
    return {
      wrapComponents: {
        errors: () => () => null
      }
    }
  }

  const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
    urls: ...,
    ...
    plugins: [
      HideAllErrorsPlugin,                // <---------------
      SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl
    ],
    ...
  })

}
```

I also recommend adding a custom `example` to the `RequestPivot` schema and/or the `SearchRequest.pivots` property to fix/work-around the `"pivots": [null]` value in auto-generated request/response examples in `POST /search`.

```yaml
  RequestPivot:
    description: A list of pivots.
    type: object
    ...
    example:     # <--- Custom example
      key: MyKey
      pivots:
        - key: AnotherKey
          pivots: []
```